# Can't get Python regex backreferences to work

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I want to match the docstrings of a Python file. Eg.

```
r""" Hello this is Foo
     """
```

Using only `"""` should be enough for the start.

```
>>> data = 'r""" Hello this is Foo\n     """'
>>> def display(m):
...     if not m:
...             return None
...     else:
...             return '<Match: %r, groups=%r>' % (m.group(), m.groups())
...
>>> import re
>>> print display(re.match('r?"""(.*?)"""', data, re.S))
<Match: 'r""" Hello this is Foo\n     """', groups=(' Hello this is Foo\n     ',)>
>>> print display(re.match('r?(""")(.*?)\1', data, re.S))
None
```

Can someone please explain to me why the first expression matches and the other does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the escape sequence `\1` instead of the backreference `\1`.

You can fix this by changing to escaping the `\` before `1`.

```
print display(re.match('r?(""")(.*?)\\1', data, re.S))
```

You can also fix it by using a raw string for your regex, with no escape sequences.

```
print display(re.match(r'r?(""")(.*?)\1', data, re.S))
```

Comment: That's actually tough to spot! To my eye, I had a  hard time recognizing that `'r?(""")(.*?)\1'` was not `r'?(""")(.*?)\1'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the `re.DOTALL` or `re.MULTILINE` flags. In this case a `re.DOTALL` should allow your regex `.*?` to match newlines as well